# Simple Integral Involving the Square of the Elliptic Integral

Tags: integration, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

I have,

$$
\int uE^{2}\left(u\right)du
$$

where $E$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind:

$$
E\left(k\right)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}
$$

I've tried integrating this by looking for something that differentiates into $E^2(u)$, though can't seem to find anything. Any help?

Comment: Do you specifically need an anti-derivative? Or would it suffice to obtain the definite integral over some interval?